# Cohort analysis, Making groups by user sign up date in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have data table like below, having unique user id(id) and the date of sign up(created_at).

[image]

What I want to do is making groups of user IDs by the date of sign up, and doing cohort analysis such as which group of people makes us more profit etc.

How can I make filter / calculation / function to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a calculated field called, say, **signup_cohort**, defined as:

```
datetrunc('day', created_at)
```

Or if you want to group users who signed up in the same month or quarter, change the first argument accordingly.

I would make that field a discrete dimension by default.

There are fancier things you might want to do with LOD calcs, but I'd start with this.